# Are C# non-generic types unbound or bound?

Tags: c#, generics, terminology

[C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#constructed-types) says:

> The term unbound type refers to a non-generic type or an unbound
>   generic type. The term bound type refers to a non-generic type or a
>   constructed type.

So if a type is not a generic type is it bound or unbound?

Comment: Im not sure the question make sense. if a type is known at runtime and constructed, in my mind its bound implicitly. if its not, its unbound, until its bound at runtime. however the terminology here is a little loose for my comfort and i could be completely wrong

Comment: @TheGeneral The question makes a lot of sense to me at least. The OP is saying that the spec seems to say that a non-generic type is both a bound and unbound type, and the OP is asking which one it actually is.

Comment: Bound.. unbound.. Now I want to know it too. Anyone? Why is it important to know? How this information is useful? To whom? To compiler? To me? To achieve what? Is it something to do with late binding or what? Until today my life was happy without knowing anything about bound/unbound...

Comment: @Sinatr as John Skeet says, it is really unimportant terminology. And you will probably never use it. But I usually analyze every detail in the book that I am reading. Now I am stuck with bound, unbound and constructed types.

Comment: @saidfagan, *"you will probably never use it"* - all I want to know, thanks. I'd never read specification of anything in sane mind. User manual - yes, API - probably, Errata - maybe, huge book with thousands of words - run in panic...

Comment: @Sinatr I do not read a specification, too. I reference it in some cases. I am reading a book and met this terms. It will be great to understand the exact meanings of these terms. However, answers on SO and specification really confuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search I found an [article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1648574&seqNum=4) which quotes Eric Lippert:

> Yes, nongeneric types are considered to be both bound and unbound.

Which answers my question.

Comment: Obviously I found this strange enough to call it out in the annotated specification; it is a really odd bit of jargon!

Comment: It's seems like they wanted to extend the concept of bound/unbound (that makes great sense for generics) to non-generics also.I don't get this.For sure it would require some explanation that Microsoft doesn't provide. What does it mean for a non-generic, say a string or whatsoever to be unbound? It requires to have some of the carachteristics of unbounds. That actually is only one: not being real types (they need type arguments) cannot be used for instantiaton,  for declarations of variables of parameters or whatsoever. So cases are: a string cannot be istantiated or it's not an unbound type.